# Bash script to remove unwanted git objects

Tags: bash, git

A while ago, someone at our office thought it'd be a great idea to start tracking a number of fairly large binary files in one of our more important repositories. We noticed our builds were slowing down (considerably) and fetching new changes from the remotes could take for up to a minute.

We eventually noticed that there were quite a number of reasonably large objects in our repos, and I was appointed to clean up the mess.
seeing as these objects had been added, removed updated, renamed and replaced in various commits, across a fair number of branches, I decided to write a script to rewrite the head's of all of these branches automatically, instead of going through all the files, and all the commits individually.

Not being a Bash ninja, I stuck to what I know, using a lot of `$(<command> | grep | sed | awk )`  trickery. I've always gotten by using this approach, but I'd really like to know if bash offers some features I've yet to uncover, that would enable me to write, essentially, better scripts. Hence, I'd like to get some feedback on the type of scripts I'm currently writing, and how I could do better:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SCRIPT=$(basename ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})

verbose=false
idxfile="packidx.log"
forcepush=false
filterflag="--index-filter"
#get current branch
currentbranch=$(git branch | grep '*' | awk '{print $2}')

function Help {
    echo "Usage $SCRIPT [-svfh][-i value]:"
    echo "     -i [packidx.log]: specify an existing file, containing sorted git verify-pack -v output"
    echo "                       Default is to create or prompt to reuse an existing packidx.log file"
    echo "     -v              : verbose output"
    echo "     -s              : slow, use tree-filter instead of index-filter when removing objects"
    echo "     -f              : Force push. Whenever an object is removed from a branch, perform a force-push"
    echo "     -h              : Help. Display this message"
}

function AfterFilter {
    if [ "$verbose" = true ] ; then
        echo 'cleaning up .git/refs/original and .git/logs, then gc the git DB'
    fi
    rm -Rf .git/refs/original
    rm -Rf .git/logs/
    git gc
    if [ "$verbose" = true ] ; then
        echo 'object-count stats after filter'
        git count-objects -v
    fi
    git prune --expire now
    if [ "$verbose" = true ] ; then
        echo 'object-count stats after prune'
        git count-objects -v
    fi
    echo ''
    if [ "$forcepush" = true ] ; then
        git push --force
    else
        read -p 'push the rewritten head? [Y/n]: ' -n 1 -r
        if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[nN]$ ]] ; then
            git push --force
        fi
    fi
}

if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
    while getopts :isvfh flag ; do
        case $flag in
            i)
                idxfile=$OPTARG
                ;;
            f)
                forcepush=true
                ;;
            v)
                verbose=true
                ;;
            s)
                filterflag="--tree-filter"
                ;;
            h)
                Help
                exit 0
                ;;
            \?)
                Help
                exit 1
                ;;
        esac
    done
fi

if [ ! -f $idxfile ]; then
    REPLY=y
else
    read -p "create $idxfile file? [y/N]: " -n 1 -r
fi
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[yY]$ ]]
then
    echo "Creating $idxfile on branch $currentbranch"
    git gc
    packfile=$(ls .git/objects/pack/*.idx)
    git verify-pack -v "$packfile" | sort -k 3 -n > packidx.log
fi

for objectref in $(tac packidx.log | grep blob | cut -d " " -f1); do
    if [ "$verbose" = true ] ; then
        echo 'object-count stats'
        git count-objects -v
    fi
    if [ "$verbose" = true ] ; then
        echo "get filename for object $objectref"
    fi
    filename=$(git rev-list --objects --all | grep $objectref | sed -n -e "s/^$objectref //p")
    read -p "process all commits modifying $filename? [y/N] " -n 1 -r
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        if [ "$verbose" = true ] ; then
            echo "get all commits modifying $filename"
            git log --oneline --branches -- "$filename"
        fi
        # output is for user info only, use commit refs here:
        commits=() #array of commits
        commitlength=0
        for commit in $(git log --oneline --branches -- "$filename" | awk '{print $1;}'); do
            commits[commitlength]=$commit
            commitlength=$((commitlength+1))
        done
        if (( commitlength == 0 )) ; then
            echo "No commits found for $filename, must be a dangling object"
        else
            commitlength=$((commitlength-1)) #last commit
            for (( i=commitlength; i>0; i--)); do
            #while [ $commitlength -ge 0 ] ; do
                for branch in $(git branch --contains ${commits[$i]} | cut -c 3-) ; do
                    #which branch is rewritten is considered vital info, verbose or not
                    #echo this line
                    echo "rewriting $branch for commit ${commits[$i]}"
                    if [[ ! "$branch" =~ "$currentbranch" ]] ; then
                        git checkout $branch
                    fi
                    git filter-branch --force $filterflag "git rm --ignore-unmatch --cached $filename" --prune-empty -- "${commits[$i]}"^..
                    AfterFilter
                    if [ "$verbose" = true ] ; then
                        echo "$branch rewritten"
                    fi
                    if [[ ! "$branch" =~ "$currentbranch" ]] ; then
                        #return to current branch
                        git checkout $currentbranch
                    fi
                done
                echo $i
            done
            #checkout the initial branch
            git checkout "$currentbranch"
        fi
    fi
    read -p 'continue? [Y/n]: ' -n 1 -r
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[nN]$ ]]
    then
        break
    fi
done
echo '' #insert blank line
read -p "remove $idxfile? [y/N]: " -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[yY]$ ]]; then
    rm $idxfile
fi
```

Comment: what's the problem with `git rm`?

Comment: @Vogel612: That's what I'm doing in the `git filter-branch`  bit. The problem is that the repo has had several hundred Mb's in bin files added to it. you can remove these files from git using `git rm`, but the commits containing those files still hold a reference to them, and so `git rm`  will not remove the objects from the repo, resulting in a `git clone` that pulls close to 2Gb's, half of which is old bin files that shouldn't have been tracked in the first place

Comment: Essentially, to remove a file that has been committed and pushed, there's no alternative to filter-branch (rewriting all the commits that point to the file, and force-pushing the altered commits). You can find more details [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Removing-Objects)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is not needed. `env` is used to modify the working environment, and since you don't use any of its options, you don't need it. Basically, you're just spending an extra process fork. Just use bash directly: `#!/bin/bash`.
2. You name your variable `SCRIPT`, which is a useful name but also uppercase. Uppercase variables are usually reserved by the bash environment. While this is not particularly wrong, you should avoid it to prevent overwriting an important reserved variable like `PATH`.
3. You get the script name from the command: `basename ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`. While this is also not wrong, the modern way would be: `{0##\*/}`, which is more efficient since it doesn't call any program. Also, since you're only using this variable once in the `Help` function, it would make more sense to embed `${0##\*/}` directly without creating a new variable as it is a ready-made variable.
4. You name your usage function `Help`. This is not wrong of course, but a more traditional Unix-ish name would be `usage`.
5. In the `Help` function, you call `echo` several times, which is clearly not so efficient (or well-looking). A traditional solution would be to use `cat` like this:

   ```
   cat << _EOF__
   Usage ....
   ..
   _EOF__
   ```
6. You test: `[ "$verbose" = true ]`. If you already know that `$verbose` would be either `true` or `false` (which you do, in this case), you can just: `if $verbose; then` because `true` is treated as a command this time, and it will simply return 0.
7. Since you are regularly checking for true values, you can use a shortcut:`$var && if_true_commands`. So instead of saying `if [ "$verbose" = true ] ; then echo ..` you can just say `$verbose && echo ..`. For example, you say:

   ```
   if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[nN]$ ]] ; then
       git push --force
   fi
   ```

   You can say:

   ```
   [[ $REPLY =~ ^[nN]$ ]] || git push --force
   ```

   This is not all that different, but that's how modern bash scripting style does it, and you have to admit, that's fancier.
8. Small notes:

   - You say on line 85: `packfile=$(ls .git/objects/pack/*.idx)`. However, by using glob expansion, you've already listed the files yourself. So, practically, using `echo` would be slightly more efficient.
   - I noticed that you usually omit double-quoting variables and commands. This might result in undesired expansion behaviour, so you just get the first word of output usually accompanied by some bash errors and warnings if more than one word was split.
   - You use `echo ''` to output an empty line. Well, believe it or not, empty arguments like this one is just ignored by bash, so what you really ran was `echo`. Hopefully for you, `echo` just outputs an empty line when it doesn't get any arguments, which is what you wanted after all.
   - For further syntax checking and suggestions, you can check [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net).

Comment: I didn't know about http://www.shellcheck.net/, nifty!

Comment: ditto... thanks for letting me know about shellcheck